# Setting an environment in subprocess to execute a batch file

Tags: python, subprocess, virtualenv

I tried to set an environment with a *.sh file in a bash shell and then to execute a batch file with python subprocess. Here is my code:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(". ./bin/testenv.sh", ["start", "-b", "cm.bat"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, executable="/bin/bash")
p.communicate()
```

But this does not work. I need the stdout and stderr. I work in ubuntu.
As far as I understand when I do all these processes by hand I would use the built-in function source for the environment. It seems that this is not so easy to export in subprocess. In the subprocess docs under `popen constructor` I read about `env`, but I unfortunately do not understand how to use that correctly, I am not even sure if this could help me.
How can I make my problem work? (Or are there any other possibilities to treat this problem?) 
Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to set an environment variable?

Comment: inside my bat file there are some commands which can only be interpreted in this environment. Also the command `start` is only excecutable in this env.